# Limiting SQL Full Text Indexing

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I was wondering if there was a way to limit my Full Text Indexing to, in laymen terms, include a `WHERE` clause.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Order] KEY INDEX [PK_Order] ON [ft_Order] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Order] ADD ([Email])
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Order] ADD ([Address])

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Order] ENABLE
```

The [Order] table also has a column for [IsPending], and I was trying to see if it was possible to only index when the [IsPending] column is a certain criteria.  Other potentials solutions are an indexed view, but I was hoping there was another clever solution that I have not been able to successfully find.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. And I think an Indexed View *is* the clever solution, not sure I would have thought of that. [Don't forget `NOEXPAND`](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints)

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: See also [Why Full Text’s CONTAINS Queries Are So Slow](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/11/why-full-texts-contains-queries-are-so-slow/)